# How to create a video with audio comment?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I want to make a tutorial video where I explain something. 
In most commercial video editors, there is the possibility to see a video and to start a live audio record.

Is something like this also possible with Blender, or do I have to record my commentary separately outside of Blender, and then hope that video and audio fit together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blender has no audio recording functions. You could simply play your animation and record with [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) to MP3.

The recordings can be arranged in [*Video Sequence Editor*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Sequencer/Usage) (VSE) to synchronize them with the video , it might be helpful to record a each few sentences to a separate files.

Image of the VSE while moving around audio tracks:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to "hope".
Just record a screencast with audio with software like [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/) (Windows/OSX) or [Simple Screen Recorder](http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/) (linux) and if needed edit it later. Or - as suggested - record audio separately with [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) and stitch it together with software of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

New quicktime also allows you to record from builr in mic and camera on a mac.

Comment: The OP means to do the audio recording IN blender, which is not currently possible yet.