# How to record a Blender tutorial for others

Tags: interface, windows

I've gotten so much from this great Blender community, I'd like to give back. Before I start I'd like to ask how to do this best.

Questions:

- How do you record a Blender tutorial in Windows?
- What do you have to set to see the keystrokes and mouse presses (or anything else that is worth showing)?
- Which recording software do you use to record the Blender window? Or can Blender do the recording itself?
- Can you record the Blender window alone or do you have to let it run in fullscreen to hide other elements like a taskbar?
- Any additional suggestions?

Comment: Depends on your OS.

Comment: This is a quite good question, but regrettably most of it is out of scope for this site, on the one hand, an too much opinion based, on the other. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: @brasshat maybe better move it to: http://video.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @brasshat I thought so too. But then again it's Blender related. I've seen there's some screencast plugin for Blender, so I guess you could do it all in Blender alone. But I don't know if that's the proper way. After all versions change, methods improve, etc. The tutorial I've seen creates a gazillion of pngs. I rather prefer to have a movie and not have to convert pngs to a movie.

Comment: LukeD, I wouldn't object to moving it there, but I'm not graced with the authority to move it myself.

Comment: Roland, I agree that there is some Blender association, and if the question were edited so as to deal with the aspects specificly, I'd withdraw my close vote, but as written,  I think it is out of scope here.

Comment: This could be Blender related if you use its built-in functionality to capture; thus [ScreenCast addon](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Screencast_Key_Status_Tool) for keystrokes and Capture tool for animation itself. You can find *some* of tips [on meta](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers) however you'll want to choose another file format.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15830/how-to-create-a-video-with-audio-comment/15838#15838 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23059/how-do-i-display-what-keys-i-use/23060#23060 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/555/screen-recording-with-blender/73923#73923 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41911/what-does-the-make-screencast-button-do/41912#41912

Comment: @cegaton Thank you very much, I'll check out the links.

Comment: @Mr Zak Thank you, that's very helpful. I always wanted to know how people create these animated gifs here on the blender site.

Comment: "Bandicam"  records all or any part of the screen you zoom into.  It can be paused etc.  It's also free but I did pay for it.  Not sure if I got any extra for that but the "Bandicam" imprint disappears from your outputs.  I agree with the BSE site sentiments.  Have learned a lot from other people's difficulties.

Comment: I figured you can record a video all inside Blender itself. Only problem is the showing of the keys and mouse movement. It got removed for a reason. But without adding an alternative.